# Flask HTML emails is not rendered

Tags: email, flask

I have a flask application, where I want to send an email, along with some data fetched from a form. Everything works fine, but the issue is, that when the email is received the HTML code is not rendered it is only displayed the raw code. Here is what I have done so far

```
if google_response['success']: #this line is used for a ReCaptcha response
    msg = Message('Thank you for contacting me', sender='(my email address is put here as a string)', recipients=[request.form['email']])
    name = request.form['name']
    msg.body = render_template('email.html', name=name)
    mail.send(msg)
    return render_template('index.html')
else:
    return render_template('index.html')
```

What, am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming this has to do with how you are creating your email. You should be using a `Multipart Email` to do so. My guess would be that you're using using your HTML as the text for the email and not actually attaching it to the email.

Since you haven't provided us with any of that code, I'll give you an example of how to generate an email that includes HTML formatting.

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

to_address = ''
from_address = ''

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = ''
msg['From'] = from_address
msg['To'] = to_address

text = ''
html = 'your HTML code goes here'
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()

mail.login('', '')
mail.sendmail(to_address, from_address, msg.as_string())
mail.quit()
```